# Does either ability of the thrown weapon fighting style affect boomerangs?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter

The thrown weapon fighting style says:

> You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon.
> In addition, when you hit with a ranged attack using a thrown weapon, you gain a +2 bonus to the damage roll.

Boomerangs, listed [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/boomerang), and the Storm Boomerang which is not in SRD, don't have the thrown property.  This would seem to exclude them from the first ability which is very explicit about what it affects, and possibly exclude them from the second, depending whether "thrown weapon" refers to a weapon with the thrown property or to any weapon that is thrown to make a ranged attack.  This seems absurd though.

Comment: Note that the boomerang on D&D Beyond [is not an official weaopn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132560), it is more of a technical requirement of the website. The [Storm Boomerang](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/Storm-Boomerang) is the official "version"

Comment: Yes I'm aware, the storm boomerang page just blocks me out because I don't have the book on the site.

Comment: The boomerang is also the *only* ranged weapon without one of ammunition or thrown.

Answer (score 11):

#### The Fighting Style does little (if anything) for Boomerangs

The Fighting Style states:

> You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon. In addition, when you hit with a ranged attack using a thrown weapon, you gain a +2 bonus to the damage roll.

The first part applies only to weapons with the thrown property, which the Storm Boomerang (and "regular" Boomerangs) do not have.

The second part applies to attacks "using a thrown weapon". *Unfortunately* 5e chose to use standard English, meaning we cannot actually tell whether this meant "a weapon that has been thrown" or "a weapon with the thrown property" which are rather different phrases. After all, you can throw a club (or any other weapon) by making a ranged improvised attack.

5e gives us *no* way of determining which of these phrases it meant so it will be up the GM to determine which interpretation to use and thus, whether or not Boomerangs and improvised ranged attacks using weapons benefit from the Fighting Style.

Personally, because "thrown" *is* a game-defined property, I would assume it is intended to mean that property; but 5e does not capitalize, italicize, or otherwise differentiate between something being thrown and something having the thrown *property*, so that's just what *I* would do.

---

#### This makes *no* sense to me

This is why, at my own tables, I would have the Fighting Style work perfectly well with Boomerangs because they *should* have the thrown property (they have a short and long range and are literally thrown), but the rather unusual item (the Storm Boomerang) does not have this property. I would remedy this at my own tables.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, improvised weapons get the thrown property if you're throwing them, but as the boomerang is already a ranged weapon it doesn't count as an improvised thrown weapon. Honestly I don't think it matters but it could be a balancing thing with its returning feature

Comment: I don’t see anything in the [rules for improvised weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons) that says thrown improvised weapons get the **thrown** property, where are you getting that from?

Comment: An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage (the GM assigns a damage type appropriate to the object). If a character uses a ranged weapon to make a melee Attack, or throws a melee weapon that does not have the thrown property, it also deals 1d4 damage. [An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a Long Range of 60 feet.] Maybe I read that wrong but throwing a Melee weapon is an improvised thrown weapon no? Like it adds both the improvised and thrown weapon tags?