# Are there any additional weapons in official sources, other than the PHB?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

I was wondering how many (simple and martial) weapons in **official** D&D 5e source books (adventures, campaign settings, etc.) other than the *Player's Handbook* (and excluding magical variants of existing weapons)?

Is there a complete list somewhere?

---

*Note:* I'm aware that there are some in the *Monster Manual*, such as:

- A Grimlock's spiked bone club
- A Kuo-toa's pincer staff

But those "weapons" are part of the monster stats, and not really aimed at players, and I don't think they are even classified as either simple or martial weapons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The full catalogue can be found on D&D Beyond.

D&D Beyond has all the available weapons in the equipment section of their site, using [this search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment?filter-search=Weapon). These results include the adventure-specific Ylkwa and Hoopak, as well as the [firearms featured in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Firearms). (They also include the unofficial firearms published in third-party Critical Role content; these are noted with "(Exandria)" in the item name.)

Aside from the weapons found in the PHB and DMG, the following weapons can be found:

- [Ylkwa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/yklwa), *Tomb of Annihilation*
- [Hoopak](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/hoopak), *Dragonlance: Shadow of the Dragon Queen*
- [Double-Bladed Scimitar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/double-bladed-scimitar), *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*

Comment: I keep going back and forth in my head about this. On one hand, the link is good and it's a complete answer. On the other hand, should the link die (somehow), wouldn't it be better to have the list here as well? Or maybe list the source books that have weapons not listed in the PHB?

Comment: @TheLittlePeace I can list the sourcebooks, sure. I won’t reproduce the whole list though. DND Beyond is owned by WotC now, so it’s here to stay.

Comment: Right - I wasn't thinking it was going to go away :) Just maybe they re-do how the site works someday and the link breaks. But that can be fixed. +1 from me now.

Comment: The list also doesn't list the source books, which doesn't help. For example: it includes the Boomerang, but does not say what source book it originates from :-(

Comment: @Jacco: Note – a nonmagical boomerang doesn't actually exist anywhere in official content, but DDB needed to add a nonmagical weapon to use as a base when implementing the *storm boomerang* magic item from the *Princes of the Apocalypse* adventure.

Comment: @V2Blast Would that make the boomerang an official weapon as opposed to technical homebrew, now that WotC owns it? I ask based on [this question on it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132556/60441). If it is an official weapon now, it should probably get an honorable mention in this answer as the only location it's listed, and the answers in the linked question should probably be reconsidered for current standing.

Comment: @TheLittlePeace The simple fact that WotC bought DDB doesn’t change the status of an item that is an artifact of digitizing D&D content for use with their online tool. There are numerous documented errors in DDB’s presentation of Wizard’s printed content. Are these errors “official” just because Wizards owns the site now? Of course not. Most of these are errors are just artifacts of how the site is built and the content implemented in their online tools.

Comment: I doubt DDB is going anywhere, but I could easily believe that as 5e sunsets and One becomes the priority for support, current DDB links will degrade over time.  That is a potential issue far larger than this question though, as such links permeate the site.